# Is it bad practice to equal() class instances by just their unique instanceID?

Tags: java, equals, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I have a class that, on instantiation, creates a unique ID for its objects like so:

```
public class Foo {

    private final static AtomicInteger UNIQUE_ID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final int id;
    private final String name;         
    private final int hashcode;
    public Foo(String name) {
         id = UNIQUE_ID.GetAndIncrement();
         this.name = name;
         int result = 17;
         int result = 31 * result + id;
         int result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
         hashcode = result;
    }
    public int getInstanceID() { return id; }
```

Now I want to implement hashCode and equals this way:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Foo))
            return false;

        Foo other = (Foo) obj;
        return other.getInstanceID == getInstanceID();
    }

    public int hashCode() { return hashcode; }
}
```

Is it considered bad practice if I just compare the ID of the objects diregarding any other field that might differ from one Foo istance to the other? Additionally should I still regard every field in the hashcode function or also just use the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. The contract goes like this - *If two objects are equal, they must have the same `hashCode`*. You haven't Overridden `hashCode()`, so you can have 2 equal objects with different hashcode which is wrong. override `hashcode()` to adhere to the contract, then it might *just be fine*.

Comment: Yes I know about the hashCode() contract and I of course implemented it. So my hashcode function should still use all the fields if I implement it?

int result = 17; result = 31 * result + id; result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();

Comment: @Jan - That's the catch. Your `hashCode()` should follow `equals()` i.e, the *contract doesn't specify what all fields should be included*. `return 5` is a valid `hashCode()` implementation. The only thing that matters is *for any 2 instances `x` and `y` if `x.equals(y)` is true, then `x` and `y` should have the same `hashCode`*

Comment: Ok so I could easily just return the instanceID with the hashCode function and It would be perfectly fine, because I know that every class ID will be unique? Or should hashCodes be globally unique if possible?

Comment: @Jan - Nope. They don't have to be globally unique. They should just be consistent.  For example `s1=new String("abc")` and `s2 = new String("abc")` are two *different* instances which are `equal`. So the hashCodes will be same for the 2 instances.

Comment: So, as soon as I know, that two object instances should never be considered equal, I can just implement equals like this: `return obj == this` and hashCode can also just stay the default way as it probably uses the uniqueness of instances?

Comment: @Jan - The default `equals()` method actually does that :P. So, if you don't override `equals()`, you don't have to override `hashCode()` :P

Comment: :D Okay the quintessence is: If you never want two different class instances to be considered equal, just don't override `equals()` and `hashcode()`. Enlightening. :)

Comment: @Jan I am struggling to understand why this answer was accepted, given it doesn't really answer the question, which is about implementing *both* equals and hashCode by using only *some, not all* instance fields. Anyway, my answer would be that yes, you can just use the "ID" field, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Rogério - And in your understanding this answer is wrong because?

Comment: It's not *wrong* per se, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Rogério - Well, I answered the OPs question in comments as well :)

Comment: Yes, I see that, the comments add what was missing in the answer itself. Could you edit the answer to include all the relevant information? Some (most?) people will not read all the comments, so...

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to implement the hashCode function in such a way so that it distributes the objects in a collection(hashtable) evenly. The objects which produce the same hashCode go to the same bucket. The job of hashCode function is to identify the bucket.

If you have a bad function which returns same value for all, then imagine the objects are all stored in one bucket. This makes the job difficult for the collection as it has to go through each object and run equals method on them till it finds the right one if available.

When you have a good hashCode function, then distinct objects are identified by distinct buckets. Therefore fewer objects in a given bucket, which means less search needed.

It is a good idea to use the properties of your object to uniquely identify it.